# Plotting k-Means clustering output

Tags: java, r, plot, k-means

I have clustered my dataset using 'k-means' in java and below is the output of my clustering algorithm.

```
List<Cluster<T>>  finalClusters = doClustering();

public <T> Cluster(){
   public T centroid;
   public List<T> classifiedPoints
   public int classification ;   
 }
```

Any class of type T would be as follows

```
  T {
 double[] attributes;
  }
```

Now I want to plot this output like below and is there any Java plotting library for this or I have to write this output to file and plot it using R.

[image: k-meansoutput]

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by `attributes` here ?  are attributes your input data?

Comment: @agstudy attributes are my input data

Answer (score 1):

You can connect java to R using `rJava`. It is relatively simple. I show below a scenario that I would use.

First I write an R code to cluster data and plot them using only R functions. For example you can do this :

```
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
(cl <- kmeans(x, 2))  ## you replace kmeans by your call to java function
plot(x, col = cl$cluster)
points(cl$centers, col = 1:2, pch = 8, cex = 2)
```

Then you replace the call to `kmeans` by a call to your java function:

```
 library(rJava)
.jinit(PATH-TO_YOUR_CLASS_BIN_OR_JAR) # this starts the JVM
 ## I call a the Cluster constructor giving  it the imput data 
 ## Obvsiouly you should create this constructor
 javaCluster <- .jnew("Cluster",.jarray(x,dispatch=TRUE))
 ## call th clustering function which returns a vector of integers
 cl <- .jcall(javaCluster ,"[I",method="doClustering")
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

- or do it entirely in `R` ... :)
- or connect `Java` to `R` using [RServe](http://rforge.net/Rserve/), which has a Java Client. You can also find a decent amount of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rserve) tagged so in SO